# Preventing Z-fighting on coplanar polygons?

Tags: opengl, rendering, render, polygon

I'm trying to deal with Z-fighting on co-planar polygons in an OpenGL based renderer.  Due to legacy issues I have my hands tied in many regards. Mainly the renderer has to be myopic due to how the data flow works within the older systems.

Users are able to draw geometry in arbitrary positions and I have no real method of detecting when they've decided to overlap two polygons.  With glPolygonOffset I'd need to have that knowledge to offset on or the other of the polygons.  I'm also fairly sure playing with the projection matrix won't help matters as the Z-fighting is coming from round off error due to the co-planar nature of the data.  Turning depth-writing on and off isn't really an option either as I don't know when this problem is about to occur during the render loop.

So suggestions?

Comment: How about a small random `glPolygonOffset()` on every polygon?

Comment: Without any real knowledge of when or where this will happen, you can't just wave a magic wand and fix it. All actual fixes are ultimately predicated on being able to have some control over the renderer itself.

Comment: Try glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL) or glDepthFunc(GL_LESS).

Comment: I have full control over the renderer, just not over the data/tessellator.  I figured I was pretty much SOL, but it never hurts to ask.

Oh and I am using glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)

Answer (score 2):

The Red Book has some. For example you could first render all the coplanar polygons into the stencil buffer, without touching the color buffer (i.e. `glColorMask(0,0,0,0)`) but doing Z tests and updating the depth buffer. Then turn of depth testing and depth writes, enable color writes and stencil test and render the polygons in their layering order; the stencil buffer will apply the result of the earlier depth test preparations.